# Force real network usage - disable loopback interface for applications

Tags: networking, iptables, interface, traffic

I am trying to test some network properties with a (partially self written) tool chain.
As I would like to use one device with two WLAN adapters / interfaces, I have to prevent communication over the loopback interface and create **real** network traffic. The test inspects functionality, including ping, arp, multicast etc.

How do I force process 1 to use interface wlan1 only and process 2 the interface wlan2?
I guess, this is a job for some magic *iptables* rules set?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way developed by Daniel Ryde, which uses a self developed c-programm, which tells the *dynamic linker to first load all libs into the process you want to run and then add some more ontop of it*.

This explanation at [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes) and this  discussion on [Daniel Lange's blog](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html)
may be helpful, but is there really no way to do it with the Ubuntu/Linux build-in tools?